# Is there a way to convert just the string of an input to integer?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this problem where the input has both strings and integers in it. I'm wondering if there is a way to ignore the string part or convert the string to an integer in order to do math with the integer part. An example input would be "a1".

Comment: Python is a good approximation of a turing complete language. There is a way. But your question makes no attempt to follow site guidelines, and is off topic as posed.

Comment: The user is a new one - the problem posed is a valid one, I think the question just needs some editing

Comment: Can you give us more example(e.g. what should "a1b2" be? A list of integers [1,2]? Or convert it by digits i.e. 12?)

Comment: Hi, the problem is determining with an input of coordinates what color a square of a chessboard is. I was thinking I could just see if the number was even or odd and from there see which color it is, but I can't do math with the string in the input. So the only inputs would be a1 through a8, b1 through b8, etc. Hopefully this makes the question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
int(''.join(i for i in s if i.isdigit()))
```

First creates a string of all digits, then converts to integer.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Loop
Here is the Code for this :

```py
AllNums=""
n = input()
operations = ['+', '-', #Add all operators]
for i in n :
     if i.isdigit() or i in operations :
          AllNums+= i

print(eval(AllNums))
```

Comment: From what I see, this code enumerates string for certain operations. But why don't you just use `eval(n)`? And I don't think that this is the OP wants.

Comment: If you'll directly use eval(n), it will return error if you enter something like a1 or such that is asked in the question, moreover, eval only evaluates, it cannot seperate strings and numbers and then process those numbers for mathematical Operations

Comment: I suppose that's true. You can still use list comprehension and `eval()` instead though. But I still don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I think he asked to input a string with alphabets, Symbols and numbers and operations and output only the operation part (ignoring all alphabets or symbols). Like input a12g3-e20-i3 outputs 100